# How to align imageView in centerVertical in Relative Layout Android

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout

I am trying to design a row for list ... It contains 1 checkbox , 2 textView , 1 ImageView and 1 Rating Bar ...

1. After adding rating bar ImageView is not in centerVertical according to the Relative Layout
2. I have used  **android:layout_marginRight="70dp"** to fix it on the right position but I want to fix it using **android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_image"**

**Here is the xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <!--  ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:src="@drawable/bday"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Ravi Ranjan" />

        <!-- GENDER -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gender"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/checkBox1"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="12dip"
         android:text="Male" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gender"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:rating   = "4"
        android:textSize="12dip"
         android:text="1 Aug" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
        style = "?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@id/gender"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

Use `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` for **thumbnail** `LinearLayout`

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
        android:padding="3dip" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:src="@drawable/bday" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the below solid layout which will support almost all screens as per your need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <!-- ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
        android:padding="3dip" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:src="@drawable/bday" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ravi Ranjan"
            android:textColor="#040404"
            android:textSize="15dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <!-- GENDER -->

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gender"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Male"
                android:textColor="#343434"
                android:textSize="12dip" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gender"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:rating="4"
                android:text="1 Aug"
                android:textColor="#343434"
                android:textSize="12dip" />
        </TableRow>

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it will help you..